# for listing values from db using codeigniter rest for web service

Tags: codeigniter

to list the values from db i have been using the followin code

model

```
function user_list_community($serviceName) {
        $ipJson = json_encode($input);
        $this->db->select('*');
        $this->db->from('community');
        //$this->db->where('user_id', $input['user_id']);
        $query = $this->db->get();
        $result = $query->result();
        if (!empty($result)) {
            $data['list_community']= $result;
            $data['message'] = 'User details retrieved successfully.';
            $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status('success', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        } else {
            $data['message'] = 'Unable to retrieve.Please the user id';
            $status = $this->ville_lib->return_status('error', $serviceName, $data, $ipJson);
        }
        return $status;
    }
```

controller

```
function list_community_post(){
         $serviceName = 'list_community';
         $retVals = $this->user_model->user_list_community($input, $serviceName);
         header("content-type: application/json");
        echo $retVals;
        exit;
    }
```

the issue am facing is am getting the values but am getting error as follows. what was the wrong am doing here. can someone help me . thanks.

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined variable: input

Filename: controllers/users.php

Line Number: 57

A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Notice

Message:  Undefined variable: input

Filename: models/user_model.php

Line Number: 67

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting error because $input is not defined in the code. So you should either this:

```
    function list_community_post(){
    $input='';
    $serviceName = 'list_community';
    $retVals = $this->user_model->user_list_community($input, $serviceName);
    header("content-type: application/json");
    echo $retVals;
    exit;
  }
```

or

```
    function list_community_post(){
    $serviceName = 'list_community';
    $retVals = $this->user_model->user_list_community($serviceName);
    header("content-type: application/json");
    echo $retVals;
    exit;
  }
```

Comment: i used as you said but still am getting the following error    <div style="border:1px solid #990000;padding-left:20px;margin:0 0 10px 0;">

<h4>A PHP Error was encountered</h4>

<p>Severity: Notice</p>
<p>Message:  Undefined variable: input</p>
<p>Filename: controllers/users.php</p>
<p>Line Number: 58</p>

Comment: hi girish i have one more doubt can i ask you?

Comment: Hello user2739848, actually i just forget to remove $input from the second one so the notice was comming, so now use second and it will also work

Comment: i have input in this format {"community" : [{"community_id":1},{"community_id":2},{"community_id":3}]} how to post it to model decode it store in db. can you help me for that please.

Comment: function join_community_post(){
  $serviceName = 'join_community'; 
  //getting posted values
  $c =  '{"community" : [{"community_id":1},{"community_id":2},{"community_id":3}]}';
  $ip = trim($this->input->post($c));
  $ipJson = json_decode($ip);
  print_r ($ipJson);exit;
  $retVals = $this->user_model->user_join_community($ip, $serviceName);
  
  header("content-type: application/json");
  echo $retVals;
  exit;
    } hai girish i gave controller in this way but am getting nothing what i have to do

Comment: Use json_decode() founction to get data in array format from json

Comment: yeah i used that but its not working i have sent code just look into it and say what was wrong

Comment: function join_community_post(){
    $serviceName = 'join_community';    
    //getting posted values
    $c =  '{"community" : [{"community_id":1},{"community_id":2},{"community_id":3}]}';
    $ipJson = json_decode($c);
    print_r ($ipJson);exit;
    $retVals = $this->user_model->user_join_community($ip, $serviceName);

    header("content-type: application/json");
    echo $retVals;
    exit;
} hi girish i used as above its working but how to pass this post this values to model inorder to save in db

Comment: your data gives result as:-                                     stdClass Object
(
    [community] => Array
        (
            [0] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [community_id] => 1
                )

            [1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [community_id] => 2
                )

            [2] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [community_id] => 3
                )

        )

)                                                                   So I think it is easy to manipulate.

Answer (score 0):

Just like it says on the tin. Your $input variable is not created anywhere, just passed as a parameter to the json_encode and user_list_community functions.

Comment: how to remove it and give

Answer (score 0):

the function user_list_community(**$serviceName**) doesn't have two arguments while you calling it with $this->user_model->user_list_community(**$input, $serviceName**);

try function user_list_community($input, $serviceName);

And ofcourse you have to pass value for $input arguement as above said.

Comment: what i need to pass into that